# Python - spur ssh command messing up file paths

Tags: python, linux, ssh, paramiko

I am using spur in python 2.7, ssh'ing into a linux box, but for some reason it is messing with my file paths. here is the command:

```
import spur
outFile = "'%s'" % outFile
shell = spur.SshShell(hostname=self.run_params["host"], username=self.run_params["username"], password=self.run_params["password"], missing_host_key=spur.ssh.MissingHostKey.accept)
print outFile
result = shell.run(["ln", "-sf", movFile, outFile])
```

This is the output of the `print outFile`:

```
'/RAIDS/RAID_1/Unmanaged/platform-deliveries-103_1/Content/_GOOGLE/Ninl/NBV_1234-source.mov'
```

But when I run the command I get this error with the outFile:

```
RunProcessError: return code: 1
output: b''
stderr output: b"ln: creating symbolic link `\\'/RAIDS/RAID_1/Unmanaged/platform-deliveries-103_1/Content/_GOOGLE/Ninl/NBV_1234-source.mov\\'': No such file or directory\n"
```

What is adding the \\ at the beginning and at the end of my link?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I was using outFile = "'%s'" % outFile to account for spaces in the file path, with spur doesn't need. Removing this fixed the issue.